How do I fix all terminal output being yellow on linux? (No gui installed)
All output of the terminal is tinted yellow, to the point of being nearly unusable. yellow terminal
It came with ubuntu installed (no gui), which had the same issue, I then installed rocky linux.
Windows, the bootloader/GRUB, the rocky linux installer, and the BIOS/UEFI screens all look fine. I've tried 2 different monitors. I've tried DisplayPort and HDMI. GPU is a Titan V. It's a dell 7875 workstation we installed our own GPUs in.

What you're looking for is a way to change the background color of the terminal. There should be something you can execute to change terminal settings; it might be as simple as including a background color escape sequence in your default prompt.

This does not look like a single background color. Possibly a problem with the GPU at a specific resolution/frequency setting.  You can try setting a different vga mode.

The background color of the terminal is set in the Terminal settings. I don't know where that is for the screen you're using, but try $ printf "\033[30m"; that should change your background color to black, and make it easy to work with.
